# RabbitMQ started but can't access management interface

Tags: rabbitmq, localhost

I have `RabbitMQ` installed and started. The service is running as well. However, when I try to open the management interface in firefox, I get this error:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:#####. (##### being several port numbers i tried).
```

I checked the ports and made sure that they were correct as well as trying to reinstall `RabbitMQ`.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I think you should check a few things:

the management plugin is not enabled by default, you need to run the below command to enable it: (see https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Also this runs on port `15672` by default, it is possible the server/network is blocking this port. You will need to check that the port is open.

Comment: You have to run the above command from 'sbin' folder in RabbitMQ installtion path (e.g. C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.4\sbin)

Comment: this was only part of the problem for me, right now rabbitmq keeps restarting. so no solution yet

Comment: after following all the comments here I am finally able to run http://localhost:15672/

Comment: yes, it run on `http://localhost:15672/` but In code, I have to specify the port as `5672` not `15672`. any idea why?

Comment: @roottraveller 5672 is the port of the actual server, 15672 is the port of the web-based management interface tool

Comment: For anytone with the same issue, you need to open the sbin RabbitMQ Server folder under Program Files on the console. It does not work on the PowerShell

Comment: cd C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.16\sbin and then ./rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management and than go to http://localhost:15672/

Comment: Same problem, in my case the solution was restart after apply the command

Comment: I run the command. Console write success message with plugin enabled. But still cann not access localhost:15672

Comment: surely there is a configuration option in rabbitmq.conf for this - a better answer might have that? this is dumb

Answer (score 33):

The problem is because you need to enable the plugins in RabbitMQ, in order to enable that open "**RabbitMQ Command Prompt (sbin dir)**" and run the following command

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

It will enable all the plugins that is associated with the RabbitMQ.
Now open the browser and type http://localhost:15672 it will open a RabbitMQ console login with `guest` as username and `guest` as password.

Comment: Regular Command line only, power shell does not seem to work. Thanks

Comment: You are a Saviour :)

Comment: Worked for me, but before that had to set env variable correctly for erl, see my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Sometimes, on Windows, it's not enough to do just `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. UI is accessible only after reinstalling RabbitMQ

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled and it started working (Windows 7 Enterprise)

Comment: superb. all docs say you do NOT have to re-install. After your comment I have re-installed. waisted a lot of time till I found this answer!

Comment: I have done rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management and (re)installed RabbitMQ.. It worked . Thanks

Comment: Yes reinstalling was the key, the plugin was already enabled running rabbitmq-plugins list

Comment: Thanks a lot, reinstalling works for me, Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Chrome please try with Firefox, I had the same issue on Chrome however it worked fine on Firefox.

Comment: Fixed using Firefox instead of Chrome browser

Answer (score 5):

1-
install erlang & Set environment variables:

```
Variable name : ERLANG_HOME
Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\erl6.4

note: don't include bin on above step.
```

2-
Add %ERLANG_HOME%\bin to the PATH environmental variable:

```
Variable name : PATH
Variable value: `%ERLANG_HOME%\bin`
restart
```

3- In Windown, delete everything in `c:\Users\--USERNAME--\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\`

4- run RabbitMQ command prompt (sbin directory) from start menu and type this command:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

5- see the RabbitMQ Managment in:

```
http://localhost:15672/
```

username = guest

password = guest

Answer (score 3):

I am using `rabbitmq` container. What made the UI available (under http://localhost:15672/) again for me is stopping/starting the container:

```
> docker stop <container-id> 
> docker start <container-id>
```

Comment: You can also do this by clicking the Play button in the Docker Desktop windows app on the container itself.

Answer (score 3):

In Windown, For some reason delete all folder in `c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\` (xxx is your username)

start rabbitmq `net start rabbitmq`

check rabbitmq `service rabbitmqctl status`

Then restart the rabbitmq server from Windows start option.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,The rabbit mq in browser runs on `http://localhost:15672/`. I was trying to access `http://localhost:5672/`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to do this under windows just go to the installation directory for RabbitMQ Server in the sbin directory (mine was at C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.10.7\sbin) and there you can run the bat file to enable RabbitMQ:

```
.\rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Answer (score 1):

Do follow Ashwini's answer, before that set environmental variable like below ->

- Set environment variable:

  Variable name : `ERLANG_HOME`

  Variable value: `C:\Program Files (x86)\erl6.4`

note: don't include bin on above step.

2- Add `%ERLANG_HOME%\bin` to the PATH environmental variable:

```
Variable name : PATH
Variable value: `%ERLANG_HOME%\bin`
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (i am updated RabbitMq) worked this:

- Delete all files and folders in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
- Reinstall RabbitMq
- Clear cookies or use another browser
- Go to http://localhost:15672/ and Ctrl + F5

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this answered here so I thought I'd include it. You can pull the rabbitmq image from dockerhub with the `management` tag which includes the management plugin pre-enabled along side the API.

```
docker pull rabbitmq:management
```

And you can access the management dashboard via `http://localhost:15672/` like you would normally with `guest` as both username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue on Windows 10 after installing using [chocolatey](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#chocolatey). I removed and reinstall the service, but it still did not work.

I had to remove the whole RabbitMq and manually install [using the installer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html#installer).

That is rather strange, since chocolatey downloads and installs using some setup executables anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Other than having your plugin enabled, in my case I had cookies from other projects in my browser. Clearing them up has fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue.
Steps I followed:

1. I installed ERLang, then installed RabbitMQ.
2. Opened CMD on *\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.9.13\sbin* path in administration mode. *rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management*
3. Then ran rabbitmq-service.bat start command.

Result: Service started but localhost:15672 doesn't shows anything.

How I fixed it.

Uninstalled existing rabbitMQ(not ERLang).
Reinstalled rabbitMQ and followed the same process of going into the folder sbin and opened cmd and all.

Answer (score 0):

These days browsers automatically redirect requests to HTTPS, but it appears management console works only on HTTP.

Whatever browser you are using, please try to stop redirecting (best if you do that just for localhost).

For Chrome, you navigate chrome://net-internals/#hsts and add "localhost" (without quotes) into the "Delete domain security policies" input & press the button.