# Rabbitmq cannot connect to localhost

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq using homebrew on MacOS M1 chip, it's supposed to have the management plugin enabled

```
==> Caveats
Management Plugin enabled by default at http://localhost:15672
```

I double checked by running `rabbitmq-plugins list` and the plugin did enabled

```
[E ] rabbitmq_management               3.12.8
[e ] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.12.8
[E ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.12.8
```

I started my rabbitmq successfully

```
==> Successfully started `rabbitmq` (label: homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq)
```

I also tried to reinstall rabbitmq, restart rabbitmq.

I tried most of the answers on [RabbitMQ started but can't access management interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500014/rabbitmq-started-but-cant-access-management-interface)

But the **http://localhost:15672 refuse to connect**.